# First element in array of strings is empty when using split

Tags: java, arrays, file, split

So I'm trying to read some numbers from a file and put them into an array. I've been reading about people having problems with whitespace, so using trim, I did it like this:

```
String[] tokens = new String[length];
 for(int i = 0; i<length;i++){
    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    line = line.trim();
    tokens = line.split("");
    }
```

But the first element this array  (token[0]) becomes empty. Am I using the split function wrong?

Comment: You are converting line to character array. You want to split the given line with space?

Comment: MAybe change split function parameter

Comment: Yes, the argument to `split(...)` is the (regex) delimiter. So if your input is eg. `1, 2, 4, 8` you could do `split( "," )`.'

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will work with the delimiter now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the split method what character it should split on. Try this:

```
tokens = line.split(" "); //split on a space character
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you! Sometimes it's just right there in front of me!

Answer (score 1):

```
tokens = line.split(" ");
```

You forgot whitespace.